# i want to use usecontext in sessionmanger and pass the user as context , so that user can be available in universally in every component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

This is my session manager ,i have to import in every component in order to get the current user login in information. To resolve this multiple importing, i want to create context  and use context to pass the user , isloading in the body tag in layout to get the current user logged in information in every component without importing it in every page .Anyone can help me.

Sessionmanager:

```
const SessionManager = ({ updateUser, setLoading }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
 setLoading(true); 
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        getIdTokenResult(user)
          .then((tokenResult) => {
            const { claims } = tokenResult;
            updateUser(claims);
            setLoading(false); // Set loading to false after user data is retrieved
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error getting token result', error);
            setLoading(false); // Set loading to false even if an error occurs
          });
      } else {
        updateUser(null);
        setLoading(false); // Set loading to false if no user is authenticated
      }
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [updateUser, setLoading]);
return null;
};
```

Layout:where i want to use context and pass user in body tag

```
'use client'
import { hydrateRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'


import MainHeader from './components/layout/main-header'
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

// export const metadata = {
//   title: 'Create Next App',
//   description: 'Generated by create next app',
// }

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {

  const pathname = usePathname()
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()

  const excludeHeader = pathname.startsWith('/admin')
 const excludeHeader1 = pathname.startsWith('/blog')

  return (
    <html lang="en">
     
      <body className={inter.className} >       {!(excludeHeader ) && <MainHeader />}
{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```